# Crystal Reports 2008 - Trouble resetting a shared variable

Tags: layout, syntax, crystal-reports, formula, crystal-reports-2008

## Update: Could It be a different issue?

I'm pretty certain I've taken the correct steps, but what if it's a different issue here?

I have multiple parameters, and it seems like it may be being reset, but then the sub-reports might be calculating across all parameters regardless, so even though it's resetting, it's recalculating across all the multiple work order numbers I've specified in my work order number parameter.

## Background

I have a Crystal Report 2008 report with a few sub-reports that share their total values back to the main report for manipulation.

The sub-reports work fine for a single record but don't reset when multiple records are selected, causing them to show the total across all records.

**This is an issue with a known solution**, but when I attempt to apply it in my report, it doesn't seem to be working as expected.

I'm pretty sure it's an issue either with syntax of the formulas or with the layout of where I'm placing them.

## Known Steps to Take

The issue is that Crystal sub-reports don't specifically reset; this is by design.

To force the report to reset, you have to insert a formula in a record-level group (i.e. not report header) before the sub-report is run that sets the shared variable back to zero.

## Layout of The Report

- **Report Header** (suppressed)
- **Page Header** (basic page information)
- **Group Header 1a** -- shared variable reset formula
- **Group Header 1b** -- workorder information
- **Details** -- Subreport for labor estimates and subreport for materials estimates
- **Group Footer 1a** -- Formulas displaying the total for both subreports
- **Group Footer 1b** -- the long description of the workorder (no sub-report)
- **Report Footer** (suppressed)
- **Page Footer** (basic page information)

**Shared variable creation formula in labor subreport (placed in subreport footer):**

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
Shared CurrencyVar subTotal_LaborCosts;
subTotal_LaborCosts := Sum ({R_PFWR_ESTS_LABBYCODE.TOTALLABORCOSTS});
```

**Shared variable formula in main report (placed in main report, Footer 1a):**

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
Shared CurrencyVar subTotal_LaborCosts;
subTotal_LaborCosts
```

**Shared Variable Reset Formula (placed in main report, group header 1a):**

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
Shared CurrencyVar subTotal_LaborCosts;
subTotal_LaborCosts:=0;
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was.

## The Real Problem

The issue wasn't that the formula wasn't being reset (it was).

The problem was in the way I had linked the report fields to the subreport parameter.

I had linked the paramerter for my main report to the parameter for my sub-report. This, in effect, passed every value in the parameter to the subreport, so it ran with all the values every time.

## Fix

To fix this, I changed the value that was linked to the subreport parameter.

I changed it from the main report parameter field (which has multiple values) to a value in the main report that listed the workorder number (ensuring it would only ever have one).

Answer (score 1):

If your calculation is a scalar value, you may want to consider using a [SQL-Expression field](http://cogniza.com/wordpress/2005/11/07/crystal-reports-using-sql-expression-fields/), rather than a subreport.  The field's SQL can be correlated to the main query, probably the grouping field, your situation.

** edit **

It appears that you want a summary of labor costs for each row in the Details section and you want a summary of these in group footer.  Assuming this is accurate, follow these steps:

- Create SQL Expression:

  --{%TOTAL_LABOR_COST}
  (
  SELECT TOTALLABORCOSTS
  FROM R_PFWR_ESTS_LABBYCODE
  --link to a field in the main report, probably one that changes for each row in the Details section
  --WHERE 
  -- group, if necessary
  --GROUP BY 
  )
- Place field in Details section
- Insert a summary on this field; place in Group 1 Footer

Comment: Not sure I'm understanding correctly. The calculation I have is correct when I run the with one parameter value. When I run it with multiple parameter values for a the parameter, the subreport just doesn't reset itself to zero for when the next item is displayed, so I get the total for all displayed reports, not merely for that report. It seems this is a common issue with the solution I've seen. Could you explain how the approach would be different with a SQL expression? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the additional insight! If you wouldn't mind, please see my updated question. I'm wondering if it could be a different problem. The subreport appears to be calculated across all parameter values entered for that parameter, rather than one at a time based on whatever report record we're looking at.